# Export data as CSV in back end with proper HTTP headers

Tags: plugin-development, wp-admin, permissions, csv

I wrote a plugin that displays all products in a woocommerce store in admin settings option, now I want to add a link to download the products as CSV file.

The problem is, when I click the link I get a permission error saying I don't have permission to view this page.

Here's my code:

```
function extra_tablenav($which) {
    if ($which == "top") {
        echo '<h3 style="display:inline">'
        . __('These products are currently in the database:')
        . '</h3>' .
        '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' .
        '<a href="' . admin_url('admin.php?page=download_csv.php') . '">' . __('Export to CSV') . '</a>';
    }
}
```

How can I fix those permissions?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Do not point the URL to `admin.php`, use `admin-post.php` instead:

```
'<a href="' . admin_url( 'admin-post.php?action=print.csv' ) . '">'
```

In your plugin register a callback for that action:

```
add_action( 'admin_post_print.csv', 'print_csv' );

function print_csv()
{
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )
        return;

    header('Content-Type: application/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=example.csv');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');

    // output the CSV data
}
```

If you want to make the data available for anonymous users (not logged in), then register the callback again with:

```
add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_print.csv', 'print_csv' );
```

… and remove the capability check from the function.

Comment: Just wanted to add for future reference that adding extra parameters to the URL can be accessed in the callback function by parsing the $_REQUEST variable.

Comment: @eballeste Parsing **`$_GET`**, not **`$_REQUEST`**. Always use only the data from expected places. **`$_REQUEST`** includes POST and COOKIE data.

Comment: Just adding for further clarity that although it is true that parsing the $_GET variable to parse the URL parameters is preferable to using the $_REQUEST variable, for security purposes, you should also be using nonces. Here's a useful link: https://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/introduction-to-wordpress-nonces-5357