# How to give a download link to a .csv file from the custom plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, links, headers

I have made a custom plugin, which exports MYSQL table contents into a **.csv** file which gets saved in to wp uploads directory.
Now, I am trying to give a download link for downloading directly a **.csv** file. But, I am getting  this error "**Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent**"

I'm so very grateful for all of the help you all give. I've searched for this topic and couldn't find it, if this topic is already answered here, please comment with the link to the question with the answer.

Thanks.

**Code Which I tried for Downloaing:**

```
header( "Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0" );
header( "Content-Length: " . strlen( $out ) );

// Output to browser with appropriate mime type, you choose ;)
header( "Content-type: text/x-csv" );
header( "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename" );

echo $out;
exit;
```

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/102452/73)?

Comment: Where are you putting this code? It won't work after any HTML has been sent to the browser.

Comment: Now i have used the link as suggested by toscho by using it the errors are eliminated but download is not happening.I am just giving the link to download in the page where i want to download.

Comment: The answer toscho linked to is exactly what you're after, what part is causing confusion?

Comment: In add_action( 'admin_post_print.csv', 'print_csv' );
we are passing "admin_post_print.csv" as a name of action and what action we are specifying is "action=print.csv" in href.
So i am confused in both of these.
Can you please clear my confusion.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your plugin main file eg.... `my-plugin-def.php`

Add the following lines

```
add_action( 'admin_post_sample_data.csv', 'sample_data_csv' );

function sample_data_csv()
{
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )
        return;

    header('Content-Type: application/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=example.csv');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');

    // output the CSV data
    echo 'id,name';
    echo '1,Saran';
}
```

Where you required download link add this line

```
echo '<a href="' . admin_url( 'admin-post.php?action=sample_data.csv' ) . '">Download sample</a>';
```