# Linking Plugin Files to WP

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, forms, mysql

I am writing a plug-in right now which adds a table to the database when activated.

I have another file in my plug-in directory which handles a form submission and writes to the database. This file seems to have no link to WP, because it returns NULL when I ask for the **global $wpdb**

```
<?php
header('Content-type: '.$_POST["mime-type"].'');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$_POST["filename"].'');

global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "my_plugin";
$rows_affected = $wpdb->insert( $table_name, array( 'time' => current_time('mysql') ) );

readfile($_POST["file"]);
exit;
?>
```

If I were to make this a custom template file for some private page and then submit forms to that page I think it would work. But I know there must be a way to do this all within the plug-in directory.

#### [Plug-in Code](http://codebin.org/view/0fd722a4)

Comment: See [Export data as CSV in back end with proper HTTP headers](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/102452/73) for a guide how to send HTTP headers in a WP context.

Comment: I tried to implement what appears to be happening in the answer, I nested the contents of the form-receiving file (posted above) into a function in the main plug-in file, and then added an action. And then I submit the form to that main plug-in file with the action attached. But now it's generating some other errors. I updated the question with a link to plug-in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the "capability" to use `$wpdb` in your page.

Include this in your page and see what happens.

```
<?php    
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];    
include_once $path . '/wp-load.php';
```