# Create csv file in plugin

Tags: plugins, php, functions, csv

I have written a function to create csv file usin the below code.I am getting `Headers already sent` warning and I can't able to create the csv file too.How can I fix this problem.I have attached the code here.

```
function create_csv_file(){
$date = new DateTime();
$ts = $date->format( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );
$result = array();
$result[] = array(
    "first_name" => "Faison", "last_name" => "Zutavern",
    "product_viewed" => "Sunglasses", "time_viewed" => $ts
);
$result[] = array(
    "first_name" => "Faison", "last_name" => "Zutavern",
    "product_viewed" => "Razor", "time_viewed" => $ts
);
$filename = "report-$ts.csv";
ob_start();
header( 'Content-Type: text/csv' );
header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment;filename='.$filename);
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
$hrow = $result[0];
fputcsv($fp, array_keys($hrow));
foreach ($result as $data) {
    fputcsv($fp, $data);
}
fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: Do you call this function after headers are sent?

Comment: yes,Am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, obviously. :) Have you seen [this solution](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/102452/73)?

Comment: I am using the `create_csv_file` in my template page.Will this solution work for me?