# Export Wordpress Table to CSV from page

Tags: php, wpdb, export, csv

I want to export my members table to csv format on my default download location. So I used a shortcode in functions.php and called it on a page. I am getting an already sent header warning and csv file is not exported but data is printed on the screen with header already sent error warning. Can anybody help me export the file and also remove the error of header sent. Thanks

Error Message

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at D:\xamp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\class.wp-styles.php:119) in D:\xamp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\jupiter\functions.php on line 1005
```

Shortcode code in functions.php file

```
add_shortcode('exporttocsv','exporttocsv');
function exporttocsv()
{

$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$db = 'w';
$table = 'groups';
$file = 'export';

$link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die("Can not connect." . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db) or die("Can not connect.");

$result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM ".$table."");
$i = 0;
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$csv_output .= $row['Field']."; ";
$i++;
}
}
$csv_output .= "\n";

$values = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$table."");
while ($rowr = mysql_fetch_row($values)) {
for ($j=0;$j<$i;$j++) {
$csv_output .= $rowr[$j]."; ";
}
$csv_output .= "\n";
}

$filename = $file."_".date("Y-m-d_H-i",time());
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-disposition: csv" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv");
header( "Content-disposition: filename=".$filename.".csv");
print $csv_output;
$string=ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean(); 
    return $string;
exit;
}
```

This is how I call it on a page

```
[exporttocsv]
```

Comment: Have you tried [Export data as CSV in back end with proper HTTP headers](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/102452/73)?

Comment: @toscho .. thanks for your suggestion .. I have solved it by putting everything in a page template and writing my code before get_header();