# How to put Word documents online so they can be downloaded, printed and read via a web page?

Tags: plugins

I have lots of Word documents that form training materials for work. I would like to develop a website to act as a repository for these documents. However, rather than just store them on a web server and provide links to the files, I would like (if possible) for the visitor to be able to view the documents via the website and print it from there (or choose to download the actual Word document if they so wish).

I know that you can 'save' a Word document as a .html page and then I could potentially upload them all but I was really hoping for something a bit less clunky. And also to embed the Word documents into my web pages with a custom header/footer so they looked like a normal page on the website and fitted in with everything else.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The real problem here is the download offer. Let's separate the two tasks first, to see that better.

### Upload

#### 1. … from Word directly

Word can communicate with WordPress directly per `xmlrpc.php`. When you ope a new file, select **Blog post** as template, then enter your user credentials once. Word will remember those. It might be useful to use a separate account for that, just in case MS is phoning home that too.

Now you can publish your Word text directly to WordPress. You can also edit them later, and even import existing blog posts for further editing. Keep in mind that Word will embed its own styles directly into the HTML code. This is rather ugly.

There is a [post on WPMU Dev about the details](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-use-microsoft-word-to-publish-directly-to-your-wordpress-site/).

### 2. … as PDF

There are many drivers for Windows which allow you to print a document as PDF. Either find one with a developer API and an event handling, so you can attach an upload handler to the print action, or write a custom shell script that is watching one directory on your hard drive and will upload the file whenever one is changed or replaced.

The tricky part here is that you cannot publish a PDF as blog post, and you have to add the file to the media library. The latter can be done per XML RPC too.

### Download

If your text is stored as HTML, like in the first option, you would have to convert the HTML back to Word again. There are many tools for that. You could try [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord).

The actual WordPress handler could listen on the actions in `wp-admin/admin-post.php` as described in Export data as [CSV in back end with proper HTTP headers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/102452/73):

```
if ( is_admin() )
{
    $action = 'print_doc';
    add_action( "admin_post_nopriv_{$action}", 'print_word' );
    add_action( "admin_post_{$action}", 'print_word' );
}

function print_word()
{
    $post_id = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT );

    if ( ! $post_id )
        return;

    $post = get_post( $post_id );

    status_header( 200 );
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $post->post_name . '.docx');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');

    // Convert $post->post_content to Word
    // Output the Word document
    exit;
}
```

To create the link on the front end, you can filter `the_content`:

```
if ( ! is_admin() )
{
    add_filter( 'the_content', function( $content ) {

        if ( ! is_singular() )
            return $content;

        $post_id = get_the_ID();
        $url = admin_url( 'admin-post.php' );

        $link = sprintf(
            '<p class="download-link"><a href="%s">Download</a></p>',
            admin_url( 'admin-post.php' ) . '?action=print_doc&amp;id=' . $post_id
        );

        return $content . $link;
    });
}
```

If you have uploaded the file as PDF, use `get_attached_media()` here, filter its return value for PDF. and create the link the same way as above.

Comment: accepted this as it's the more complete answer. Thanks again for all your help :-)

Comment: How does admin-post.php differ from admin-ajax.php?

Comment: @jgraup `admin-ajax.php` does more in advance: It defines `DOING_AJAX` and it sends a `Content-Type` header. Not critical in this use case, but it does add complexity in debug situations. There is also a check for reserved actions, a moving context, that might affect your own scripts in the future.

Comment: @toscho - Thanks, I didn't know that existed.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the users to be able to edit the word documents, it might be a good option to save them as .pdf files. There are several plugins which can embed pdf's into a page, and most browsers have the ability to view and print direct from a pdf link.