# Force download of MP3 file in Safari

Tags: headers

Seeing as I have an audio player on my page I don't want safari to open the download link in a new tab with another player, I want the mp3 file to download to their computer.

My download link is located on a custom post-type index page:

```
<a href="<?php echo $audio_track_url; ?>?action=download_track" download>
    <?php _e('Download', 'txt-domain' ); ?>
</a>
```

When users click this link the file is downloaded - Using the "download" attribute works fine on most browsers but not Safari.
Currently, to work around this I am trying to modify the headers like this:

```
//force mp3 file download
add_action( 'post_type_download_track', 'force_mp3_download');
function force_mp3_download() {
    if(!is_admin()){
        header('Content-Type: application/mp3');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=example.mp3');
        header('Pragma: no-cache');   
    }
}
```

In [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/102451/export-data-as-csv-in-back-end-with-proper-http-headers) the href in the  tag is appended `admin_post.php?action=print.csv` and the action used is `admin_post_print.csv` but I'm not sure which action to use in my case?

Comment: See [Export data as CSV in back end with proper HTTP headers](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/102451/73) for how to force a download.

Comment: Thanks for the link but I have no idea how to apply that to my situation

Comment: Adjust the `Content-Type`, and send the two other headers as they are.

Comment: No i understood that part - i'm stuck on which action I should use instead of `add_action( 'admin_post_print.csv', 'print_csv' );` if my action is ?action=download_track and I'm on the frontend  index screen for a custom post type?

Comment: That depends on the way you are including the files. If you are using made-up URLs, `template_redirect` seems fine.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by including?  If i use template_redirect then the mp3 file is simply downloaded when the post type archive page is loaded.  I only want the file to be downloaded when the download button is clicked (the <a> tag in my original question).

Comment: Then you shouldn't link to the archive page …

Comment: I'm not, I'm linking to the mp3 file. Using the HTML5 Download attribute. The variable $audio_track_url is the location of the mp3 file on the server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49809/discussion-between-ralphonz-and-toscho).